# How to clear back stack from navigation controller

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

If I have 4 fragments (A,B,C and D) and I move from left to right to end at D, I want to clear back the stack till A.

so when using navigation graph, it may be in the action of C fragment
like so:

```
<action
  android:id="@+id/c"
  app:destination="@+id/d"
  app:popUpTo="@id/a"
  app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

but when am doing this, the c fragment is not cleared from backstack. It means that when I click backpress from d, c is coming and then a.
How do I solve this please?

Comment: Are you looking for A->B B->C C->D and D back to A ?

Comment: Yes i want to make to it d back to a

Answer (score 0):

To achieve `A->B->C->D` and then pressing back return to `A`:

Define in your navigation:

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/c"
        ...>

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_c_to_d"
            app:destination="@id/d"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/b"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

    </fragment>
```

And use:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_c_to_d)
```